# What does "{} = {}" do when used in Angular constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I found this snippet of code in Angular dynamic forms tutorial and I'm not sure what `{} = {}` in the constructor does.

Full snippet:

```
export class QuestionBase<T> {
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  required: boolean;
  order: number;
  controlType: string;
  type: string;
  options: {key: string, value: string}[];

  constructor(options: {
      value?: T,
      key?: string,
      label?: string,
      required?: boolean,
      order?: number,
      controlType?: string,
      type?: string
    } = {}) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.key = options.key || '';
    this.label = options.label || '';
    this.required = !!options.required;
    this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
    this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
    this.type = options.type || '';
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the default value is an empty object if one isn't supplied: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters

Comment: Are you sure this was AngularJS/JavaScript? That looks like TypeScript code to me, which means it's probably Angular 2+.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes you are correct, sorry for the confusion haha.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable name:

> ```
> options:
> ```

Type signature (note that all properties are optional):

> ```
> {
>   value?: T,
>   key?: string,
>   label?: string,
>   required?: boolean,
>   order?: number,
>   controlType?: string,
>   type?: string
> }
> ```

Default value (object with no properties):

> ```
> = {}
> ```